# wcf client and sending objects to server

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have a question...

I have a web service where the `OperationContract` are retrieve and update.

Using a cars example, I have the retrieve providing an object that contains a list of cars and how many cars. I have that configured through a class.

```
[OperationContract(Name = "**Retrieve**")]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultInfo))]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
CarInfo Retrieve(CarRequest CarRetrieve);

[OperationContract(Name = "**Update**")]
[FaultContract(typeof(FaultInfo))]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
CarUpdateInfo Update(CarUPDRequest CarUpdate);
```

Now the retrieve I do not seem to have a problem with at all. It's looking like it's providing the information; the update, however, is not working.

The `CarUPDRequest` object is defined with different classes and one of those is a list of cars.

The class is constructed much the same as the `CarUpdateInfo` and that seems to work.

On the client, I know I can would call the update. But I construct the object `CarUPDRequest` on the client.

I have the service reference namespace like `CarService`. I can actually type `CarService.` (and get the list of class methods like the `CarInfo` and `CarUPDRequest`.

A couple of things I noticed is like the `.Add` for a collection defined by a list. On the client app, I DO NOT get the Add. However, if I try the same thing local on the `CarService.cs`, it will allow me to do the add:

Example:

`CarUpd.Cars.car.add` doesn't work on the client but does work on the server. Work as in is an option.

When using something like

```
var CarUpd = new CarUpdRequest();
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, a DataContract is necessary I know that. But the message is to include a username and password and a List of Cars (VIN, Model, Color). How do you do a list in a Class using a DataContract?

Comment: Again, never mind. I solved my issue by doing a List<CarUpdate> CarUpd = new List<CarUpdate>();

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by doing a List CarUpd = new List();